# How to get models current values from a view to another?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a website where I would like to display the product name the user purchased after he was redirected from the checkout to the *thank you* page.

The problem is that I don't get how I could send a data from a view to another without creating a form in the template.

here is two example of views from **checkout_paymen**t to **checkout_confirmation** pages:

```
def checkout_payment(request):
    customer_id = request.user.profile.stripe_id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            gig = Gig.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('gig_id'))
        except Gig.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect(reverse('purchase_error_detail'))

    return redirect(reverse('purchase_confirmation_detail'))


def checkout_confirmation(request):
    #how can I get the purchased gig datas ?
    return render(request, 'purchase/confirmation.html', {})
```

**models.py Gig** contains : `user`, `title`, `price` fields.

**urls.py :** `name='purchase_confirmation_detail'`

Is there a way to get the last purchased datas avoiding using a form or the urls to get the product informations ?

Comment: You can persist data for the current session in the session dictionary. See the django docs for examples. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#examples

Comment: @HåkenLid I know this is out of the scope of my question but if I use session I'll have to permit access to the confirmation page only if the user enters the page from `checkout_payment`. Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy and fast way: **Sessions**

If all you need is a list of strings or a single string, you can just use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/). You can read about them in detail in the docs. Just save the names in some key, display them and clear them.

Better, more future proof solution but slightly more complicated: **Models**

When you are selling something, it is desirable to keep around some record of what the user bought. This can be helpful when system fails (trust me, it will) or to keep a record of everything.

It can be something as simple as:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    gig = models.ForeignKey(Gig)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Now you refactor your view in 2 ways:

1. Only the user in the transaction should be able to see the content on it.
2. Add the pk of the Gig to the url you redirected to.

Your source view should use a redirect like:

```
def checkout_payment(request):
    customer_id = request.user.profile.stripe_id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            gig = Gig.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('gig_id'))
        except Gig.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect(reverse('purchase_error_detail'))
    new_transaction = Transaction.objects.create(user=request.user, gig=gig)
    return redirect(reverse('purchase_confirmation_detail', kwargs={'pk': new_transaction.pk}))
```

And your destination view will be something like:

```
def checkout_confirmation(request, *args, **kwargs):
    new_transaction = Transaction.objects.get(kwargs.get('pk'))
    if request.user != new_transaction.user:
        return HttpResponseForbidden() # You can raise Http404 here too to hide the resource, like github does
    return render(request, 'purchase/confirmation.html', {'gig': transaction.gig})
```

Now you have access to everything you need to display.

Comment: I used a similar solution with models too where I create a new purchase for each user and display the last created transaction, glad to know that I made the right choice I wasn't sure if it was good or not to create a new model just for this purpose :)

Comment: @KasimovNuriddin Make sure that only the right user can access the view.

Comment: Yes I filtered the connected user only